# Eliminating Duplicate Numbers in Arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, duplicates

I need to know how to eliminate duplicate numbers in the same array. I only know creating arrays, getting data from user and print it out. Following shows my progress:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DuplicateElimination {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        int [] x = new int [10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){        
            System.out.println("Enter a number");

            x[i] = scn.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)
            System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

The real statement is

> Write a method that returns a new array by eliminating the duplicate values in the
>   array using the following method header:
>
> ```
> public static int[] eliminateDuplicates(int[] list)
> ```
>
> Write a test program that reads in ten integers, invokes the method, and displays the
>   result.

Comment: Why not use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)? From the Javadoc -> `A collection that contains no duplicate elements`

Comment: You cannot really eliminate duplicate values from an `int[]`. If you have (say) an array containing 1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8 and you "remove" the duplicates of 3 and 4: what do you store in their place? Zero? This will create another duplicate... The question doesn't make sense for a data structure that has a fixed number of elements.

Comment: @MikeKobit Actually I don't know how to use set method. I am a beginner.

Comment: @laune Instead of storing another numbers, I need to erase duplicates or at least store just one of them.

Comment: If you are getting input, what you can do is just ignore duplicates in the first place.  That way you will not have any duplicates in your array.

Comment: @TheBaxss The term "erase" cannot be applied to int array elements. You can (as dubstylee suggests) read in a replacement, check again for duplicates, and so on, until you have read in 10 different integer values. - If this is a course exercise, the exact problem statement might help.

Comment: @laune I updated the question and write the exact statement

Comment: @dubstylee maybe it could work but I'm not sure about what is expecting from me in the problem statement

Comment: @TheBaxss Cool. I can see two possibilities. Either you say, "It can't be done" (with a follow-up according to my argument), or you (meekly) add what is missing, i.e., a definition for the value to be used instead of the duplicates. Integer.MIN_VALUE might be one good option. - I'd *love* to have that one out with Teacher!

Comment: `return Arrays.stream(list).distinct().toArray();`

Answer (score 3):

You can use java `set` data structure to eliminate duplicates. Add each element into the set. it will eliminates duplicates

```
Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<Integer>();
set.add(1);
```

Comment: I don't know how to use set method. I am a beginner.

Comment: See also [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), if order is important.

Comment: @TheBaxss this answer shows you how to use it. Try it out, and make sure you read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Just after the statement:

```
x[i] = scn.nextInt();
```

You could loop accross the array like:

```
boolean isNumberFound = false;
for (int j =0; j<i; j++) {
    if (lastNumberScanned == x[j]) {
         isNumberFound = true;
         break;
    }
}
if (!isNumberFound)
      x[i] = lastNumberScanned;
```

If you dont want to stick with Arrays, then i would suggest you using Set data structure like:

```
Set<Integer> myset = new HashSet<>();
myset.add(scn.nextInt());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try set method next time.

Comment: I tried this but I don't know what type of variable is 'lastNumberScanned'. Is it integer ?

Comment: int i.e. same as what's the type of your array elements.